# Concatenate Task results within Job Definition?

Tags: chainlink

Within Chainlink a Job definition, how would developers go about concatenating two results, like strings (Not the sum of values)? I provided an ideal approach below.

**example1:**

```
$(result1) + $(result2)
```

**example2:**

```
string_result_1      [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path_1)" data="$(fetch_encoded)"]
string_result_2      [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path_2)" data="$(fetch)"] 
encode_data          [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes result)" data="{ \\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"assetId\\": $(string_result_1) + $(string_result_2) }"]
```

I want to be able to make a new GET request by concatenating the two results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do a [multi-word response](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/) request, and then do the concatenation on-chain. The nodes do not support concatenation at the job definition level yet

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, you could also farm all that heavy lifting, i.e. the string concatenation and response prep to a [Chainlink External Adapter](https://docs.chain.link/docs/external-adapters/).